# Distributed Median

Tags: algorithms, median

What is the most optimum method to calculate the median in a distributed setting? I want to optimize with respect to data transmission i.e. an algorithm that finds the median across data spread across multiple nodes by sending the least amount of data

Comment: What assumptions can you make about the distribution of the data across the nodes--for instance, would they be independently and randomly distributed? Also, in what sense do you mean optimum? Expected value? Worst-case value? And when you send information, is it broadcast (at unit cost) to all nodes or is it passed only between one node and another?

Comment: The data is uniformly independently distributed at random across all the nodes. I meant optimum for the expected value. Information can be sent from one node to another at unit cost

Comment: There are efficient algorithms (O(n)) for the median that rely on calculating medians of subgroups (which could be split across nodes), but I don't offhand know of any designed to optimize data transmission.